# jquery grid Edit in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

i want to change my gridview because of Customers think the gridview to modify data too troublesome, they don't want click the "edit" and "save"..so i choose jqueryGrid.anyone can post me a example?

Comment: What is your exact problem?? What you mean by ***modify data too troublesome***?

Comment: the customers think the action of "click 'edit',edit date and click the 'save' is too trouble",they want edit double click the date that want to edit,and edit them